# Master-detail view fragments using v4 support library and min SDK version-8

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an Android application which will run on both mobile and tablets from Android version 2.2 to 4.2. For that, I try to use `Fragments`. Using Eclipse, I tried to create a project with min SDK version 8 (version 2.2) and target SDK version 17 (version 4.2) and compiled with SDK 17 (version 4.2). I tried to create a master-detail view `Activity`. But it says,

> master-detail activity should have min SDK version 11 (Honeycomb).

Anyways, I will use `support-library-v4` for my Application to use `Fragments`. Is it correct to create master-detail view fragments using v4 support library and min SDK version-8 and Target SDK Version-17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can use Fragments using Support library for Pre honeycomb deveices.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, the min-11 requirement is inforced due to usage of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 for the list of items - it was introduced in API 11. Also that default implementation uses ActionBar (enables Up button), which was also introduced on Honeycomb.
So if you would like to support API level 8 you will need to change some aspects of how that implementation works.